# Vertex, edge, face select shortcut on Mac

Tags: interface

For Blender 2.8x on Mac.  In edit mode, Windows shortcuts 1,2,3 to select vertex, edge,face are not the default and select preset viewpoints instead.  Are there default shortcuts to select them on a Mac, without remapping the keyboard.  Selecting from top menu is slow.

Comment: I sorted it with the direct approach. Bought a keyboard with a numeric keypad. So far so good.

Comment: For Linux users, the 1, 2, and 3 keys on the number row switch between vertex, edge, and face selection modes respectively.